# Is it possible to overwrite if statement with a conditional ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
    ID  Date        NewDate     Flag
    1   4/22/2022   4/1/2022    no
    2   4/22/2022   4/1/2022    no
    3   3/22/2021   3/1/2021    no
    4   3/1/2021    2/20/2021   no
...... goes on
```

I would like to overwrite my first condition with second condition only when ID = 2. I have created two IF statements and trying to combine them together to overwrite the date in the same cell using 2 if statements within a cell.

First Condition

```
IF('Sheet1'[Flag]="No",'Sheet1'[Date] - 'Sheet1'[NewDate],0)
```

Second Condition

```
IF(AND('Sheet1'[Flag]="No",'Sheet1'[ID] =2),1, 0))
```

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do... but place `'Sheet1'[Date] - 'Sheet1'[NewDate]` from first condition into second condition where the `1` is?

Comment: @findwindow Added more information to my description. I want both if statements to run independently and second one to catch exception and overwrite my first condition only where ID = 2

Comment: Answer could be this - IF(AND('Sheet1'[Flag]="No",'Sheet1'[ID] =2),1, IF('Sheet1'[Flag]="No",'Sheet1'[Date] - 'Sheet1'[NewDate],0)))

Comment: You got it!....

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I have put your data.. and the formula is given below.. [image]

```
=IF(A2=2,IF(D2="no",1,0),IF(D2="no",B2-C2,0))
```

You can amend it as per your  columns. Let me know if you need any clarification.